# KeyError raised when Except KeyError has already been used

Tags: python, python-2.7

I met this problem when I was using a Python program Cupcake ToFU, full source code available at https://github.com/Magdoll/cDNA_Cupcake/blob/master/cupcake/io/BioReaders.py.

the program kept raising KeyError and crashed. When I looked into the code, I saw the script had used "except KeyError" to avoid program crash, however when I was trying to run it, program was still crashed for KeyError. Is there anyone can help me with it?

here is the error message

```
  File "/Users/wuyibo/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cupcake-6.8-py2.7-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg/cupcake/io/BioReaders.py", line 516, in process
    self.qLen = query_len_dict[self.qID]
KeyError: 'c2468/f1p1/3565'
```

and here is the code from line 507 to 518:

```
if query_len_dict is not None: # over write qLen and qCoverage, should be done LAST
    try:
        self.qLen = query_len_dict[self.qID]
    except KeyError: # HACK for blasr's extended qID
        k = self.qID.rfind('/')
        if k >= 0:
            try:
                self.qLen = query_len_dict[self.qID[:self.qID.rfind('/')]]
            except KeyError:
                self.qLen = query_len_dict[self.qID]
        else:
            raise Exception, "Unable to find qID {0} in the input fasta/fastq!".format(self.qID)
```

with the "except KeyError", the program should not crash, however when I was running it, it still crashed for KeyError.

Comment: When there is a `KeyError` in the `try` block, it can end up doing the same thing in the `except` block and triggering the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

When you get `KeyError` with `qID == 'c2468/f1p1/3565'` it will enter the except block.
Then in the try block (line 514) it gets new `KeyError` and then in the except block it try to execute the same (because self.qID never changes) that brought it here in the first place (i.e. line 516 is same as line 509).

```
>>> 'c2468/f1p1/3565'[:'c2468/f1p1/3565'.rfind('/')]
'c2468/f1p1'
```

Is it possible for `query_len_dict` to have key `'c2468/f1p1'`?

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.  I think `query_len_dict` should have this key, because I found this ID in the data I was trying to process, and that row seems to be  similar with other rows. Problem must be caused by other part of the codes.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few different ways that were on here and this was the easiest way:

```
if self.qID in query_len_dict:
    print(query_len_dict[self.qID])
else:
    query_len_dict[self.qID]=0
#query_len_dict.get(self.qID, 0)#this one works too instead of the last 4 lines
```

This also works with strings, not just number (int, float) parameters